# Finding zeroes for function $f(t) = e^{k(t-1)} -t$ for $k> 0$ analytically

Tags: functions, roots, lambert-w

I tried using Lambert W function the following way
$$e^{k(t-1)} -t=0$$
$$e^{k(t-1)}=t$$
$$-ke^{-k} = -kte^{-kt}$$
$$W(-ke^{-k}) = W(-kte^{-kt})$$
$$-k = -kt \implies t = 1$$
but this only gives me one trivial root, graphing the function clearly shows that this function has a root $t_0$ where $0\leq t_0< 1$ as well, is there any analytical way I can reach that point?
I need a general form of the root in terms of $k$ so I can apply a limit on it, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Third line makes no sense. How did you come across this? If you wanted to go the $\ln$ route it is expected to have a $\ln$ somewhere? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I simply multiplied both sides with $-ke^{-kt}$ to get the $e^{-kt}$ term with $t$ and use Lambert W.

Comment: You need another branch for $W,$ $W_{-1},$ which takes different values on the negatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: This is because the function $xe^{x}$ decreases then increases on $(-\infty,0).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that makes sense, but is there any way to apply a limit (w.r.t $k$) to $W_{-1}$ if I use it? Any way to graph it so at the very least I can graphically show that the root converges to 0 as $k$ increases?

Comment: In any even, $W_{0}(-ke^{-k})\neq -k,$ unless $k\in(0,1].$

Answer (score 1):

$$-ke^{-k}=-kte^{-kt}$$

$$-kte^{-kt}=-ke^{-k}$$

$$-kt=W_n(-ke^{-k})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n\in\mathbb{Z})$$

$$t=-\frac{1}{k}W_n(-ke^{-k})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n\in\mathbb{Z})$$

The real solutions are $t=-\frac{1}{k}W_0(-ke^{-k})$ and $t=-\frac{1}{k}W_{-1}(-ke^{-k})$.

$t=1$ holds for all $k$. Which of the both solutions is $1$, depends on $k$.